# How old can cat be a kitten

Tags: cats

How old can cat be a kitten to a mother cat given that they would have both have to be sterilised? If not sterilised they either try to breed or co-breed. Is there a record old kitten?

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking. Do you want to know how old a kitten should be before it can be sterialized? Or when to sterialize the mother?

Comment: How old can a kitten live with its mother and still be a kitten?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "kitten". As far as I know, "kitten" means "cat younger than about 7 months", but then your question doesn't make sense. Can you either use a different word than "kitten", or explain what you mean by "kitten"?

Comment: A kitten is a cat cared for by its mother

Comment: This depends very much on the personalities of the cats, I think.  Some mother cats cease mothering behavior over their kittens as soon as it is no longer actually needed, while some maintain a close bond with their adult offspring and some 'motherly' social behaviors (like grooming and correcting behavior), nearly permanently.  Even if your cat continues to act 'motherly' there is a still a good chance she would breed with the son if both are fertile; cats just don't see mating in the same way humans do, so get kittens sterilized before sexual maturity to prevent this.